# ASP.NET WebForms Data Binding Solutions

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, webforms

I am looking for some easy to use data binding to forms controls. Something that will handle formatting, validation and error handling, something that will handle filling controls from  business object/DTOs and vice versa with minimal code. I did use google and have found these two links:

- [Implementing two-way Data Binding for ASP.NET](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4659/implementing-twoway-data-binding-for-aspnet/)
- [Using Reflection to Bind Business Objects to ASP.NET Form Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478957.aspx)

I am curios if there is something newer and more complete.
Are you using FormView or manualy fill controls and variables or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I have always used the standard asp.net DetailsView/FormsView controls along with either SqlDataSource or ObjectDataSource controls to accomplish what you are trying to do.  This will allow you to do two-way data binding and with a small amount of coding with template fields you can add validation and formatting.

Take a look at http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/formview.aspx for more information.

Comment: It looks to me that there is too much plumbing code/markup to setup ObjectDataSource, not so elegant solution. I don't use SqlDataSource.